# Constrained optimization problem with indefinite integrals

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative, indefinite-integrals, lagrange-multiplier

Good evening, I have to solve the following minimization problem:
$$\min_{w(p)}: \int w(p)f(p|e)dp$$

s.t.

$$\int v(w(p))f(p|e)dp - g(e) ≥ u_r$$

where of course this last inequality is my constraint. 
I think it is irrelevant for my problem to specify the meaning of the functions, but I know also that $v’(w) > 0 $ and $v’’(w) ≤ 0$.

I proceed in this way, first I create the Lagrangian:
$$L=\int [w(p)f(p|e)dp]+λ[v(w(p))f(p|e)dp - g(e)-u_r]$$

At this point I have to take the derivative with respect to $w(p)$ and pose it equal to zero

$$ \frac{\partial L} {\partial (w(p))}=0$$

at this point I don't know how to procede; my problem is how treat those integrals.
The expected solution (first order condition) is:

$$-f(p|e)+\lambda v'(w(p))f(p|e)=0$$

Thank you very much. 
PS: I know also that p takes value in $[p_d,p_u]$

Edit: the first order condition for $w(p)$ is derived taking the derivative with respect to w at each level of $p$ separately. To see this point consider a discrete version of the model in which there is a finite number of possible p levels $(p_1,...,p_N)$ and associated w levels $(w_1,...,w_N)$. The first order condition is analogous to the condition one gets in the discrete model by examining the first order conditions for each $w_n=1,...,N$. TO be rigorous we shoud add that when we have a continuum of possible level of p, an optimal scheme need only to satisfy condition at a set of profit levels thati is full of measure.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to pose an optimization problem without limits of integration.

Comment: Unfortunately this is how the problem is proposed, I haven't limits of integration, I know that p takes values in $[p_d,p_u]$, this information can be of any help? Maybe I have to use that limits.

Comment: The point is, the problem makes no sense until you can be given a $w(p)$ and get back a number from your integration. Most likely the limits of integration are the maximal range on which $p$ makes sense.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to procede, but there must be a way because that first order condition is the solution of the problem. I added another edit to the original text, it can maybe help.